# How do I upload specific Apple Photos albums to Flickr?

Tags: photos, flickr

The Flickr tool wants to sync my entire Photos library and Apple Photos only want a to share a small number of photos to Flickr at a time.

Comment: Click on album -> Command+A to select all -> Right-click on one of the photos -> Share -> Flickr. Does that not work?

Comment: Will this be on an iOS device or a Mac?

Comment: @tubedogg it limits it to 15 or so at a time

Comment: Jamie,- Mac computer